# Can't understand how to use React Native useEffect

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I have a login view in a React Native application:

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Button, TextInput, Headline} from 'react-native-paper';
import globalStyles from '../styles/global';
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import AuthContext from '../context/auth/authContext';

const Login = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

  const setLocalStorageUser = async (user) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleNewUserPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Signup');
  }

  const handleLoginPress = async () => {
    try {
      const loginData = {
        username: email,
        password: password,
      }
      responseData = await axios.post(loginURL, loginData);

      setLocalStorageUser('user', {email: email, token: responseData.token});

      useEffect(() => {
        setUser({email: email, token: responseData.token});
      }, []);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    navigation.navigate('Home');
  }

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} value={email} label="Email" onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)} />
      <TextInput style={styles.input} value={password} label="Contraseña" onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)} />
      <Button 
        style={styles.button} 
        mode='contained' 
        onPress={() => handleLoginPress()}
        disabled={email=='' || password==''}
      >
        Enviar
      </Button>
      <Button icon="plus-circle" onPress={() => handleNewUserPress()}>
        Nuevo Usuario
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  button: {
    marginBottom: 20
  }
})

export default Login;
```

The problem is in function `handleLoginPress()`when calls `useEffect()`. I get this error:

```
[Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See url for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.]
```

I have no idea why it happens and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `useEffect` inside `handleLoginPress`:

```
  const handleLoginPress = async () => {
    try {
      const loginData = {
        username: email,
        password: password,
      }
      responseData = await axios.post(loginURL, loginData);

      setLocalStorageUser('user', {email: email, token: responseData.token});
      setUser({email: email, token: responseData.token});
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand, what does the `useEffect` hook does. According to the documentation:

> The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It was created because we didn't have a way to manage the state inside functional components. We needed to convert the component into a class and use lifecycle methods like: `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate`.

---

In your case, you don't need to use the `useEffect` hook since your action is being executed when you click the button to login.

You'd like to be using `useEffect` when:

- You need to fetch data
- You need to check if the user is logged in
- etc...

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is called as a function in the main function before return your jsx, but not inside of the other function or function arrow that you are declaring in the main function. In your case :

```js
import {Button, TextInput, Headline} from 'react-native-paper';
import globalStyles from '../styles/global';
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import AuthContext from '../context/auth/authContext';

const Login = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
     setUser({email: email, token: responseData.token});
  }, []);
  
  const setLocalStorageUser = async (user) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleNewUserPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Signup');
  }

  const handleLoginPress = async () => {
    try {
      const loginData = {
        username: email,
        password: password,
      }
      responseData = await axios.post(loginURL, loginData);

      setLocalStorageUser('user', {email: email, token: responseData.token});


      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

    navigation.navigate('Home');
  }

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} value={email} label="Email" onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)} />
      <TextInput style={styles.input} value={password} label="Contraseña" onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)} />
      <Button 
        style={styles.button} 
        mode='contained' 
        onPress={() => handleLoginPress()}
        disabled={email=='' || password==''}
      >
        Enviar
      </Button>
      <Button icon="plus-circle" onPress={() => handleNewUserPress()}>
        Nuevo Usuario
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  button: {
    marginBottom: 20
  }
})

export default Login;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

As the error says: You can set useEffect in a function component only, It's not allowed useEffect inside a function expression inside a function component.  The best solution, if you want to manage the useEffect you have to handle in the body of your component function and update the state to trigger it.